# Laravel non-overlapping scheduled job not executing

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have a Laravel Scheduled job which is defined in `Kernel.php` like so

```
$schedule->call('\App\Http\Controllers\ScheduleController@processQueuedMessages')
    ->everyFiveMinutes()
    ->name('process_queued_messages')
    ->withoutOverlapping();
```

During development, my job threw an exception due to a syntax error. I corrected the error and tried executing it again; but for some reason it won't.

I tried `artisan down` and then `artisan up`. I also tried restarting the server instance. But nothing would help. The job just didn't get executed (there was no exception either).

I realize that the problem is due to `->withoutOverlapping()`. Somehow, Laravel scheduler is thinking that the job is already running and hence is not executing it again.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Note: This solution is applicable for Laravel 5**
Later versions of Laravel have updated the `withoutOverlapping()` function. Refer to @nmargaritis's answer.

---

I found the solution by looking at the vendor code.

```
Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\CallbackEvent.php
```

It creates a file in local storage with the name `schedule-*`.

```
public function withoutOverlapping()
{
    if ( ! isset($this->description))
    {
        throw new LogicException(
            "A scheduled event name is required to prevent overlapping. Use the 'name' method before 'withoutOverlapping'."
        );
    }
    
    return $this->skip(function()
        {
            return file_exists($this->mutexPath());
        });
}

protected function mutexPath()
{
    return storage_path().'/framework/schedule-'.md5($this->description);
}
```

Deleting the file `schedule-*` at `storage/framework` resolved the issue.

Comment: Please note, the lock is stored in your selected cache. In my case, we are using redis. I had to find/delete the key in redis.

Comment: Sources:

https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.8/src/Illuminate/Console/Scheduling/Schedule.php#L55
https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.8/src/Illuminate/Console/Scheduling/CacheSchedulingMutex.php#L30

Answer (score 9):

**To anyone reading this, deleting the schedule files yourself, is not the right way to go.** You need to specify - the lock time - based on which,  withoutOverlapping prevents further tasks from running.

As cited in [Laravel - Task Scheduling](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/scheduling)

> If needed, you may specify how many minutes must pass before the "without overlapping" lock expires. By default, the lock will expire after 24 hours:

Your problem originates due to the fact that withoutOverlapping applies a default lock for 24 hours. So you had to wait for 24 hours before similar tasks are accepted. Simply adjust the lock time based on your needs by doing:

> $schedule->command('emails:send')->withoutOverlapping(10); // where 10 refers to minutes

Comment: I think the expiry time is now in seconds, not minutes: https://laravel-news.com/cache-ttl-change-coming-to-laravel-5-8

Comment: It does not appear to be in seconds https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/7.x/src/Illuminate/Console/Scheduling/CallbackEvent.php#L106  If it indeed changed in another layer of the framework, this means that they also have to change the expiresAt default value in this function, which is still 1440 (1440 mins = 24 hours)

Comment: Oh, you're right. Thanks for looking into it. Looks like they convert it behind-the-scenes from minutes to seconds here: https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/7.x/src/Illuminate/Console/Scheduling/CacheEventMutex.php#L43

Answer (score 5):

I had this problem too. There's not a proper solution for this but a workaround will solve the issue.

Go to storage/framework Folder of your project and delete all the `schedule-***********` files.

And then again try to run the cron. It will even if you use `withoutOverlapping() function`.

Hope this works for you. Ask if any doubt.

Comment: I have already answered my own question with exactly the same solution. Thanks though.

Answer (score 5):

This did the trick for me:

```
php artisan cache:clear
```

Answer (score 3):

Since laravel 8.x you can use [specific command](https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/40135) to clear mutex files, for example if task stucks because of a server reboot while task were executing

the problem of `clear:cache` is that this command clear cache for the entire application and this command just clears mutex-files

```bash
php artisan schedule:clear-cache
```

Answer (score 0):

This happened to us this week and we think we figured out the cause. Our crons run off one of our production server's site folder. Our deploy process involves having a second folder where we do deploy/build, and then do a hot folder swap at the end. Since withoutOverlapping() likely has to update a line in the schedule-* files when the process is done, the folder might be swapped mid job and the cron is unable to successfully mark the job as having been finished in the correct schedule-* file, so it thinks it's still running/stuck.

It was a rare occurrence but we're going to add a command to clear out these files after a deploy so it doesn't happen again.