# can't connect oracle database from laravel+mysql console command only while on cron job linux Ubuntu

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, oracle11g, console

**laravel Console command...**

```
public function handle()
{

            $stores_id     = $this->stores->where('status', '=', 'Active')->orderBy('code')->get(['code'])->toarray();
  //-------------error i think
        $stockHolddata = DB::connection('oracle')->table('mmpl.V_STOCK_ONHAND')
            ->whereIn('ADMSITE_CODE',$stores_id)
            ->where('QTY','!=','0')
            ->get(['BARCODE','ADMSITE_CODE','QTY'])->toJson();

    //----------------------

        $jsondata       = json_decode($stockHolddata,true);
        if(!empty($jsondata[0])){
        DB::table('v_stock_onhand')->truncate();                    
        }
        foreach ($jsondata as $val){
            VStockOnhand::create($val);                             
        }
}
```

VStockOnhand is a laravel mysql model.....
it runs fine if I directly run php artisan InsertOracle:stock in terminal
it won't work on cron job schedule

kernel.php

```
     protected $commands = [
   'App\Console\Commands\InsertOraclestock',
               ];

     protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
        {

            $schedule->command('InsertOracle:stock')->dailyAt('23:00')->withoutOverlapping();

      }
```

cron job code on crontab -e

```
    * * * * * /usr/bin/php7.0 /var/www/rep/qa/artisan schedule:run >> /var/www/rep/qa/example.txt
```

Comment: What error do you get? Check the log files.

Comment: i get no error i just tried.....try { }catch(exception $e){ .... }
it throws no error
i grabed running cron job to some text file it throws ....

`Running scheduled command: (touch /var/www/rep/qa/storage/framework/schedule-294bbe7d7c7275b83493a19e1fc$`

Comment: there's a typo `toarray()` should be `toArray()`

Comment: wait checking but i have some db insert on custom logs table to check weather its running  on cron job... it throws array 

main thing is 
it works if i directly on terminal php artisan mycommand:stock

Comment: no change... anyone ....

Comment: Check the `storage/framework` directory for a file with name like `schedule-*`. Since you have `withoutOverlapping()`, it may be the case that the presence of such a file is preventing the execution of the job. Refer this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41052802/laravel-non-overlapping-scheduled-job-not-executing/41052803#41052803)

Comment: just checked normal data insertion on Mysql is working properly at schedule time .....but still cant connect oracle and select and insert to another mysql database.....

Comment: i think its something about 
Yajra\Pdo\oci_connect()    on crontab -e  ... code